# Finding Users Who Match A Pattern Card

Tags: xconnect

I'm trying to show groups of users in xconnect who match a specific pattern card for a custom report. To do this I have tried using the `ProfileScores` facet and `ContactBehaviorProfile` facet. While using these I get an error saying their linq statement is not supported. Is doing something like this possible out of the box or would it require some kind of custom index?

Sample code I've tried:

```
    public async Task<object> GetUserFromPatternCardAsync(ID matchingPatternId, ID profile)
    {
        using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            var queryable = client.Contacts
                //.Where(c => c.GetFacet<ProfileScores>(ProfileScores.DefaultFacetKey)
                //.Scores[profile.Guid].MatchedPatternId.Value == matchingPatternId.Guid)
                .Where(c => c.GetFacet<ContactBehaviorProfile>(ContactBehaviorProfile.DefaultFacetKey)
                .Scores[profile.Guid].MatchedPatternId.Value == matchingPatternId.Guid)
                .WithExpandOptions(new RelatedInteractionsExpandOptions(WebVisit.DefaultFacetKey)
                {
                    StartDateTime = DateTime.MinValue,
                    Limit = int.MaxValue
                });

            return await queryable.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is xConnect Search does not support the indexer in this part of the query:

```
.Scores[patternCard.Guid].MatchedPatternId.Value == matchingPatternId.Guid)`
```

However it does support the Any method against the dictionary, so something like this:

```
.Scores.Any(s => s.Key == patternCard.Guid && s.Value.MatchedPatternId == matchingPatternId.Guid)
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that while using `ProfileScores` I get the error `Field could not be found in the model or the field is not enabled for indexing/searching. Path ProfileScores.Scores` but using `ContactBehaviorProfile` works. Thanks for the help!